# FATAL EXCEPTION: main and java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, sqlite

When i go to Test Level 1 activity, it stop working and unfortunately stopped working.

My **Exception** log is here:

```
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{priscillia.benkyo/priscillia.benkyo.TestLevel1}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at priscillia.benkyo.TestLevel1.displayQuestion(TestLevel1.java:193)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at priscillia.benkyo.TestLevel1.onCreate(TestLevel1.java:147)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-30 15:14:14.871: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

I using SQLite Expert Personal 3 and i save in asset folder
My **DatabaseHelper**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/priscillia.benkyo/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "Benkyou.db";
private static String Table_name="Soal";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
private SQLiteDatabase myData; 
private final Context myContext;


/**
* Constructor
* Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
* @param context
*/
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME,null,1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

//create empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database
public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();
    if(dbExist) {
        //do nothing (database already exist)
    } else {
        copyFiles();
    }
}

private void copyFiles() {
    try {
        InputStream is = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        File outfile = new File(DB_PATH,DB_NAME);
        outfile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        outfile.createNewFile();
        if (is==null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("stream is null!");
        } else {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
            //BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outfile));
            byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
            do {
                int numread = is.read(buf);
                if(numread<=0) break;  
                out.write(buf, 0, numread); 
                } 
            while (true); is.close(); 
            out.close(); 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e); 
    }
}

 /* Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the 
 application. * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't */
private boolean checkDatabase() {
    boolean checkDB = false;
    try{
        String myPath = myContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath().
                replace("files", "databases")+File.separator + DB_NAME;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);                
        checkDB = dbfile.exists();
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e){
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
    }

    return checkDB;
}

/*Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in 
 the system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled. This is done by transfering 
 byte stream.*/ 
private void copyDatabase() throws IOException{
    //Open your local db as the input stream InputStream 
     InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    // Path to the just created empty db String 
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
    //Open the empty db as the output stream 
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName); 
    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; int length; while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLiteException{


    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);


    }
@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if(myDataBase != null)
    myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/// Get Soal content////////
public Cursor getSoal_Content(int soalId) 
{
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY); 


Cursor cur;
cur=myData.rawQuery("select soal_desc from Soal where soal_id='"+soalId+"'",null);
cur.moveToFirst();


myData.close();
return cur;
};

/// Get Soal content///
public Cursor getSoal_List() 
{
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY); 
int i;


Cursor cur;
cur=myData.rawQuery("select soal_id,soal_desc,jawaban_corr from Soal",null);
cur.moveToFirst();
i = cur.getCount();
myData.close();
return cur;
};
//////////////////////////

public Cursor getAns(int soalid)
{
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);


Cursor cur;
cur = myData.rawQuery("select jawaban_desc from Jawaban where soal_soal_id='"+soalid+"'", null);
cur.moveToFirst();
myData.close();
return cur;
}

public Cursor getAnsList()
{
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);


Cursor cur;
cur = myData.rawQuery("select jawaban_desc from Jawaban", null);
cur.moveToFirst();
myData.close();


return cur; 
}




public Cursor getCorrAns()
{
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
myData = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);


Cursor cur;
cur = myData.rawQuery("select jawaban_corr from Soal", null);
cur.moveToFirst();
myData.close();


return cur; 
}
```

My **TestLevel1.xml**

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/soal"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
>     android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
>     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
>
> <RadioGroup
>     android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/soal"
>     android:layout_marginTop="43dp" >
>
>     <RadioButton
>         android:id="@+id/radio0"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
>
>     <RadioButton
>         android:id="@+id/radio1"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
>
>     <RadioButton
>         android:id="@+id/radio2"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
>
>     <RadioButton
>         android:id="@+id/radio3"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
> </RadioGroup>
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/tvScore"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
>     android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
>     android:text="Score: "
>     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
>
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/score"
>     android:background="@drawable/lanjut" />
> ```

My **TestLevel1.java**

```
public class TestLevel1 extends Activity {

    private RadioButton radioButton;
    private TextView quizQuestion;
    private TextView tvScore;



    private int rowIndex = 1;
    private static int score=0;
    private int questNo=0;
    private boolean checked=false;
    private boolean flag=true;

    private RadioGroup radioGroup;


    String[] corrAns = new String[5];

    final DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    Cursor c1;
    Cursor c2;
    Cursor c3;

    int counter=1;  
    String label;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_level1);
        String options[] = new String[19];


        // get reference to radio group in layout
        RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);




        // layout params to use when adding each radio button
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        try {
            db.createDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        c3 = db.getCorrAns();

        tvScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvScore);

        for (int i=0;i<=4;i++)
        {
            corrAns[i]=c3.getString(0);
            c3.moveToNext();

        }

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);




        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for(int i=0; i<4;i++) {
                       RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(i);

                        String text;



                      if (btn.isPressed() && btn.isChecked() && questNo < 5)
                       {

                           Log.e("corrAns[questNo]",corrAns[questNo]);

                          if (corrAns[questNo].equals(btn.getText()) && flag==true)
                          {
                              score++;
                              flag=false;
                              checked = true; 
                          }
                          else if(checked==true)
                          {
                              score--;
                              flag=true;
                              checked = false;
                          }




                       }
                  }
                tvScore.setText("Score: " + Integer.toString(score) + "/5");
                Log.e("Score:", Integer.toString(score));
            }
        });



        quizQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.soal);


        displayQuestion();



        /*Displays the next options and sets listener on next button*/
        Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(nextBtn_Listener);

    }

    /*Called when next button is clicked*/
    private View.OnClickListener nextBtn_Listener= new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((View) nextBtn_Listener).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lanjut1);
            flag=true;
            checked = false;
            questNo++;

            if (questNo < 5)
            {
                c1.moveToNext();
                displayQuestion();  
            }   

        }
    };

    private void displayQuestion()
    {
        //Fetching data quiz data and incrementing on each click

        c1=db.getSoal_Content(rowIndex);

        c2 =db.getAns(rowIndex++);


        quizQuestion.setText(c1.getString(0));


        radioGroup.removeAllViews();
        for (int i=0;i<=3;i++)
        {
            //Generating and adding 4 radio buttons dynamically 
            radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
            radioButton.setText(c2.getString(0));
            radioButton.setId(i);
            c2.moveToNext();
            radioGroup.addView(radioButton);

        }

    }



}
```

Please help.... Thank you :)

Comment: did you see this : `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 requested,with a size of 4` ?

Answer (score 0):

I can ensure you two things:

The problem is you trying to access some placeholder in a database table which not actually exist. You log show that:

```
CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 requested, with a size of 4
```

I can also ensure that, the originator is called from your TestLevel1 class onCreate functions number 90 line. This one I find as:

```
TestLevel1.java:90
```

So, I suggest you to check the line position with the reason I asked here to you.

If you required more information, please comment here the line where I ask you to check you. :)

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean... can more detail please?

Comment: Please, post the line number 90 from your TestLevel1.java file here :)

Comment: corrAns[i]=c3.getString(0);

Comment: Does your table have four 5 column?
Actually you try to access column 0,1,2,3,4.
Is it what you want?

Comment: for (int i=0;i<=4;i++)
        {
            corrAns[i]=c3.getString(0);
            c3.moveToNext();

        }

In this part, you are always try to check 5 rows, event thought you may not have five rows in entry. You always access the same column, I am sorry for the last comment as I miss-noticed some of it. But, it might be best to use hasNext() to use to check if there is any data in the next raw, rather then force to check 5 rows whenever it may be not there at all.

Comment: Can you please confirm me what will be the number of result you will be found for the case when you get this exception in your code? you may use cur.getCount() just before start your loop on line number 90 to get the result count comes from database.

Comment: i make quiz games with question and multiple choice. In line 90 is to get the correct answer for that question and check it right or not the answer that you choose. The question and correct answer is get from database

Comment: In this getCorrAns() method before return cur, add the following line:
`Log.i("My Test",""+cur.getCount());`
give me the result what you get from the log under tag "My Test".
Hope you know how to use logcat :)

Comment: Is i place " Log.i("My Test",""+c3.getCount());" in here?
 c3 = db.getCorrAns();
        Log.i("My Test",""+c3.getCount());

Comment: in logcat when i filter my test, the logcat is blank

Comment: you don't find out anything, even the tag "My Test", right?
If it is like that, you may be not select your device. Select your device from DDMS, if you are using eclipse.

Comment: The device from DDMS is blank. I use notebook to use eclipse

Comment: Okay, if you still facing problem to find out your attached device,
can you please just print the result of 
`c3.getCount()`
to anywhere in the screen of your device and provide me the value it returns.

Comment: and some special curiosity of mine about your code in TestLevel1.java file:
Line 88 to Line 92.
what actually you want to do with these code?
You also change the rows you found from c3 though you are not confirm that is this actually have the row from the database return result.
I see you are executing a loop 5 times exactly and always access sane column in 0 index.

Comment: I request you recheck those line, think much more about what you want to do, and what actually these line does :)
HappY CodinG

Comment: 10-30 08:44:56.875: I/My Test(840): 4

Comment: in my logcat:
10-30 08:44:56.886: E/CursorWindow(840): Failed to read row 1, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 4 rows, 1 columns.
what solution for that?

Comment: For the previous log, the reason is now clear, as you have get only 4 rows and try to access row 5 through the loop, the cursorIndexOutofBoundException occured

Comment: what solution for this: 10-30 09:58:51.207: E/AndroidRuntime(914): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{priscillia.benkyo/priscillia.benkyo.TestLevel1}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0?

Comment: can you change the current log on your question with the previous one, it will be better to see the full log for me :)

Comment: Please, check this line
TestLevel1.java: Line 193
If you can't find out the reason of the bug, please, write here the line.

Comment: Cursor cur;
 cur = myData.rawQuery("select jawaban_desc from Jawaban", null);
 cur.moveToFirst();
 myData.close();


 return cur;

Comment: do the same `Log.i("My Second Test",""+cur.getCount());`
just before the line `cur.moveToFirst();`

Comment: the code that I gave you before is wrong, the correct code  is for (int i=0;i<=3;i++)
  {
   //Generating and adding 4 radio buttons dynamically 
   radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
   radioButton.setText(c2.getString(0));
   radioButton.setId(i);
   
   c2.moveToNext();
   radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
   
  }

Comment: when i put Log.i("My Second Test",""+c2.getCount()); before c2.moveToNext(); can't find my second test tag

Comment: put the log before your loop start, and give me the output